# Create non fast-forward commits as default

Tags: git, git-gui

I usually want to create non fast-forward commits.
I know I can do that using the `--no-ff` flag, but I tend to forgot that :(

Is there a way to set this as default?
Currently I'm using Git GUI (on Windows), is there any hook that could be used?

Comment: Do you mean non-ff _merges_? Specifically on `pull` or all the time?

Comment: Specifically which Git GUI are you using, or are you using [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually want the same, so I set `merge.ff` to `false` in my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
git config --global merge.ff false
```

Unfortunately, that means all merges will be non-fast-forward... even those coming from your origin.  So I use another alias to help fast-forward the updates I do want:

```
[alias]
    ff = "!sh -c 'git merge --ff --ff-only ${1:-\"@{u}\"}' -"
```

This way I can do my fetch, and then `git ff` to fast-forward the master branch.  I've also been making use of a script to help keep my local branches up-to-date, called [`git-ffwd`](https://github.com/jszakmeister/etc/blob/master/git-addons/git-ffwd).

So the work of updating, I've allowed fast-forward updates (and want them), but in the default merge case it will always generate a merge commit.  I've found this to be a useful way to work.

This is the workflow from my command line... unfortunately, I'm not sure if GUIs cooperate well with arbitrary Git commands. :-(  But I've found the command line more useful in getting the workflow that I want.